# Como mostrar acentos no python?

Tags: python-3.x, codificação-de-caracteres

Eu estou precisando ler um arquivo de nomes em python, mas eles estão cheios de acentos, eu estou usando isso para abrir

```
arquivo = open('dadostxt/Nomes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

eu coloco utf-8 no encoding, mas quando eu vou passar para o excel ou dar um print, no lugar dos acentos ele vem com ponto de interrogação, tem como resolver isso?

exemplo do output

```
{'nome': 'Aid�e Dias', 'idade': 33, 'email': 'Aid�e Dias@gmail.com', 'salario': 4473.75}
```

Comment: O arquivo Nomes.txt foi salvado com a codificação UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

Tenta colocar isso no começo do seu programada, na primeira linha:

```
#encoding: utf-8
```